# Transfer token to wrong adress that have been created by the transaction

Tags: transactions, wallets, tokens

I have used etherdelta to transfer tokens instead of the withdraw option and they transfer tokens from my personal wallet to a new one that doesn't exist .The destination adress (automatically fill on etherdelta) looks like mine but only one character is different from my personal wallet . I didn't pay enough attention and the tokens ended up on a new wallet that have been created by the transaction :

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x2a5795ced528e332be0aaaeb36b7409f316de294352ddd7f6e45243712732bb7

Do you know if the private key have been generated during the transaction and if it s stored somewhere ?Is there any solution or the tokens are locked up for ever?

Answer (score 1):

If EtherDelta does not have the private key, I am afraid they really might be locked up.

You could leave a message on the address where your token has gone:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x0168459886bd2aa322c18bed0b209887095afcac#comments

If someone happens to generate a private key to this account, they might be so kind to send you the token back.

Have you reached out to EtherDelta?

Comment: Ether delta is very hard to reach out ... I have contacted monetha but they can't do anything. 
I have read that the private key could have been generated by the transaction which has been signed by my private account and the key is store somewhere but i don't have any idea how to find it .
If a developper know how it works when a wallet is created by a transaction it could just tell me if there is a way to get back the token or i should just give up . 
Thanks for the answer smaco.

Comment: Addresses are generated through hashing. If the address is one character off from your address, then there's no way to get it other than generating private keys for the next billion years

Answer (score 1):

Well this sucks, your tokens are locked forever. You should definitely spam them to fix this case, because it's their fault they messed up their software. The tokens are locked until someone create this address, there is no way to find private key by public key.